# facing difficulty passing values from view to controller

Tags: grails

I am using Grails, and a beginner. could somebody guide me through the following problem:

I want to pass the values in a select option along with an id to the controller from the view. I have tried using remoteFunction, createlink to pass the params through javascript but failed. Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Think you're going to have to add an example of what you tried and what the failure was to the question

Comment: Please rephrase "I want to pass the values in a select option along with an id to the controller from the view." this sentence. you wants to pass values to select or pass selected values to controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. define select in gsp

   ```
   <g:select name="id" from="${1..5}" noSelection="['-1':'所有']" class="form-control" value="${selectedIds}"/>
   ```
2. define change function in  block

   ```
   <g:javascript>
       $("#id").change(function(){
           var id = $("#id").val();
           $.post("${request.contextPath}/formUrl",{id:id},function(data){
               });
           });
   </g:javascript>
   ```